# Kotlin - R.string que envia números

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, kotlin

en la app que estamos creando en Android, se está haciendo multilenguaje pero por alguna razón en el en un fragment al intentar tomar el valor dado en *res/values/strings* me regresa números, estuve investigando y no tengo idea de porque no me muestra el valor especificado, alguien me podría ayudar con el tema y decirme ¿porque me envía números en ves de el valor que le puse?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes obtener el texto almacenado en `strings.xml` usando el metodo `getString()`,  de otra forma estas obteniendo el id del recurso por esta razon ves numeros, realizalo de esta forma:

```
val texto : String = getString(R.string.VuelosTituloVuelo)
```

de esta forma automaticamente se tomara la cadena en el lenguaje configurado.

Puedes revisar la documentacion:

[Recursos en strings.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#kotlin)

---

En el caso de tu còdigo este es un ejemplo:

```
viewHolder.itemView.item_vuelo_title_textView.text = viewHolder.itemView.context.getString(R.string.VuelosTituloVuelo)
```

Comment: Si me sirvió, muchas gracias!